# How to get the day number of a date from a month in momentjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I tried to get the day number of a choosen date from a month by using momentjs.

**My scenario is, i chose a date, like, 4-3-2023, and i want the output as 4 that it is 4th day of the month**.
I searched in web but didn't get the way as every solutions are related with moment().day or moment().daysInMonth().

i am expecting the the day number from the date i have chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your expected result by using,

```
moment('your_date').format('D')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with the following code:

```js
// Get the date of month
moment().date(); // Output assuming March 4th, 2023: 4
```

You can find more documentation and examples at https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/